# How to read SharePoint webhook logs?

Tags: sharepoint-online, webhooks

We have SP webhook configured to pickup changes in Doc library(SPO). it seems the webhook does not fire in some occasions (1 in 100). Is there anyway to troubleshoot what went wrong and why webhook did not fire for those specific cases?

Thank you.

Comment: The compliance center might help but if you're certain it's not firing for an event, you might have to contact Microsoft support since this is entirely server side and out of our control.

Comment: I'll check with support. It just skipped one event. Later events worked fine. I wonder if this is a known issue.